# Can you help me crack the code?

Tags: cipher

Being an assassin and a hacker, you have successfully infiltrated the base to steal some secrets. While cracking the code, you noticed a clock stopped at 6 p.m. and some strange numbers on the lamp and wall... Maybe there's something to it.

Hints:
L=2
R=4

3 digit code.

Comment: Are the "strange numbers on the lamp and wall" intentionally left out? What kind of clock is it (analog or digital)?

Comment: The lamp has L=2 written on it and the wall has the R=4 written on it. It's an analog clock.

Comment: Hm. If these numbers are written on the wall and lamp, why not mention it in the text directly? To me, a hint is something additional that does not belong to the puzzle proper. Perhaps "3 digit code" is a hint, perhaps it is part of the puzzle, too. (Three-digit code for what? A safe where the secrets are? That's not clear.) Perhaps you could edit the question to make it clearer. Also: How do you know whether it's a.m. or p.m. on an analogue clock?

Comment: Well the the clock in an hour fast and the wall needs better insulation, but I feel no closer to a solution

Answer (score 1):

I personally do not think this question is quite clear, but

> it is common sense that L would stand for left, and R would stand for right. We can see that exactly three numbers appear in the puzzle - the clock which is pointing toward **6**, and L=**2** and R=**4**.

> We can assume that L would mean the leftmost digit of the three-digit passcode, and R would mean the rightmost digit, so the passcode would be $2\_4$. Filling the only number in the clues left, which is 6, the answer might be $264$.